# Measuring time results in return values of 0 or 0.001

Tags: c++, windows, time, c++11, c++-chrono

I am trying to use `chrono::steady_clock` to measure fractional seconds elapsed between a block of code in my program. I have this block of code working in LiveWorkSpace ([http://liveworkspace.org/code/YT1I$9](http://liveworkspace.org/code/YT1I%249)):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
       std::vector<int> v(i, 1);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count();

    std::cout << "seconds since start: " << ((double)difference / 1000000);
}
```

When I implement the same idea into my program like so:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
// block of code to time
auto end = std::chrono::stead_clock::now();

auto difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()

std::cout << "seconds since start: " << ((double) difference / 1000000);
```

The program will only print out values of `0` and `0.001`. I highly doubt that the execution time for my block of code always equals `0` or `1000` microseconds, so what is accounting for this rounding and how might I eliminate it so that I can get the proper fractional values?

This is a Windows program.

Comment: Try `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's a good suggestion, but `steady_clock::now()` should already be accurate to nanoseconds, or at least ticks (100 nanosecond intervals).  I suspect there's a math problem here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Oh, perhaps the misplaced parentheses in the cast?

Comment: @KerrekSB Which misplaced parentheses? Looks correct to me.

Comment: @KerrekSB For what it's worth, the return values are the same whether I use `high_resolution_clock`, `steady_clock`, or `monotonic_clock`. They are always either `0` or `0.001`.

Comment: Is `// block of code to time` the for loop from the previous example?

Comment: Yeah, definitely a math error then.  Note that 1000000 is an integer, not a floating point number.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I've tried revising it to `((double)difference / 1000000.0)` with the same results.

Comment: @raphnguyen: What compiler? I cannot reproduce the issue on Windows.

Comment: @JesseGood: This is in VS2012, so I assume it is using the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: @raphnguyen: I used the same compiler and have different results with the code you posted. What happens when you set the precision before outputting? `std::cout.precision(10);`

Comment: @JesseGood So as it turns out, using the for loop example will properly print out fractional seconds. However when I apply the very same method to time the `start`, `end`, and calculate the `difference` in my program, it only prints out `0` and `0.001` as stated before. What accounts for this difference between two programs if the function calls and variable declarations are exactly the same? The only difference is the block of code I am measuring has different logic. I don't see how that can affect the time measurement, though. Any ideas?

Comment: @raphnguyen: I found out it is a bug in there implementation. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running some tests on MSVC2012, I could confirm that the C++11 clocks in Microsoft's implementation do not have a high enough resolution. See [C++  header's high_resolution_clock does not have high resolution](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443/) for a bug report concerning this issue.

So, unfortunately for a higher resolution timer, you will need to use `boost::chrono` or QueryPerformanceCounter directly like so until they fix the bug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);

    LARGE_INTEGER start;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

    // Put code here to time

    LARGE_INTEGER end;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&end);

    // for microseconds use 1000000.0
    double interval = static_cast<double>(end.QuadPart- start.QuadPart) / 
                      frequency.QuadPart; // in seconds
    std::cout << interval;
}
```

Comment: Ah, no wonder it wasn't working properly. I'd like to understand more about the `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` function and what it is actually doing. Should I always call that function before I start my timer or is it a function that only needs to be called once during the program? Have we divided the frequency correctly? The results are now giving me seconds in the hundreds, which doesn't seem correct either.

Comment: @raphnguyen: `QueryPerformanceFrequency` should only be called once during the program to get the frequency. The example I shown was in `microseconds`, if you want seconds remove the `1000000.0`. I changed the code to seconds.

Comment: @raphnguyen: `QueryPerformanceFrequency` returns the frequency in counts per second, so you if you divide the number of counts by that, you get seconds.

Comment: It seems to only be returning `0` now. What is the precision of these Query functions? I don't exactly know what time should be expected. The sample given shows a time of 0.002 seconds for the find function that I am implementing. It is a binary search for a key reading the file off of the disk, so I imagine that it would take at least 0.001 seconds to seek through the file.

Comment: OMG, they resolved it as "deferred"!  Yay!  Yay yay yay yay yay!  That's been the single thing I've requested on every survey Microsoft sent me in the last couple years, that they would stop (ab)using the "WONTFIX" closure reason for things they agree should be fixed but it's too late for the version being readied for release.

Comment: @raphnguyen: Jesse's modification to use seconds instead of microseconds actually broke it.  Division by `1000000.0` was causing a conversion to `double`, but the new code uses integer division. Perform the `static_cast` before the division and it should work again.

Comment: @Jesse: You broke it again, by doing subtraction after division.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Good eye. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @JesseGood: Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yeah, thanks! I need to be more careful. (It seems you made an edit to fix it for me, but somehow I didn't see that and things got really confusing...).

Comment: @Jesse: I'm pretty sure it's right now, and should help future visitors also, so it's all good.

Answer (score 10):

This question already has a good answer.  But I'd like to add another suggestion:

Work within the `<chrono>` framework.  Build your own clock.  Build your own time_point.  Build your own duration.  The `<chrono>` framework is very customizable.  By working within that system, you will not only learn `std::chrono`, but when your vendor starts shipping clocks you're happy with, it will be trivial to transition your code from your hand-rolled chrono::clock to `std::high_resolution_clock` (or whatever).

First though, a minor criticism about your original code:

```
std::cout << "seconds since start: " << ((double) difference / 1000000);
```

Whenever you see yourself introducing conversion constants (like 1000000) to get what you want, you're not using `chrono` correctly.  Your code isn't incorrect, just fragile.  Are you **sure** you got the right number of zeros in that constant?!

Even in this simple example you should say to yourself:

> I want to see output in terms of seconds represented by a double.

And then you should use `chrono` do that for you.  It is very easy once you learn how:

```
typedef std::chrono::duration<double> sec;
sec difference = end - start;
std::cout << "seconds since start: " << difference.count() << '\n';
```

The first line creates a type with a period of 1 second, represented by a double.

The second line simply subtracts your time_points and assigns it to your custom duration type.  The conversion from the units of `steady_clock::time_point` to your custom duration (a double second) are done by the `chrono` library automatically.  This is much simpler than:

```
auto difference = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start).count()
```

And then finally you just print out your result with the `.count()` member function.  This is again much simpler than:

```
std::cout << "seconds since start: " << ((double) difference / 1000000);
```

---

---

But since you're not happy with the precision of `std::chrono::steady_clock`, and you have access to QueryPerformanceCounter, you can do better.  You can build your own clock on top of QueryPerformanceCounter.

`<disclaimer>`

I don't have a Windows system to test the following code on.

`</disclaimer>`

```
struct my_clock
{
    typedef double                             rep;
    typedef std::ratio<1>                      period;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period> duration;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<my_clock>  time_point;
    static const bool is_steady =              false;

    static time_point now()
    {
        static const long long frequency = init_frequency();
        long long t;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&t);
        return time_point(duration(static_cast<rep>(t)/frequency));
    }
private:
    static long long init_frequency()
    {
        long long f;
        QueryPerformanceFrequency(&f);
        return f;
    }
};
```

Since you wanted your output in terms of a double second, I've made the `rep` of this clock a `double` and the `period` 1 second.  You could just as easily make the `rep` integral and the `period` some other unit such as microseconds or nanoseconds.  You just adjust the `typedef`s and the conversion from `QueryPerformanceCounter` to your `duration` in `now()`.

And now your code can look much like your original code:

```
int main()
{
    auto start = my_clock::now();
    for (unsigned long long int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
       std::vector<int> v(i, 1);
    }
    auto end = my_clock::now();

    auto difference = end - start;
    std::cout << "seconds since start: " << difference.count() << '\n';
}
```

But **without** the hand-coded conversion constants, and **with** (what I'm hoping is) sufficient precision for your needs.  And with a *much easier* porting path to a future `std::chrono::steady_clock` implementation.

`<chrono>` was designed to be an extensible library.  Please extend it. :-)

Comment: Arguments to QueryPerformanceCounter() and QueryPerformanceFrequency need to be LARGE_INTEGER microsoft types, per my experience on VS 2017 15.6.7.

Comment: Is there a reason why is_steady = false?  I would assume the QueryPerformanceCounter is a steady_clock.

Comment: @TysonHilmer:  Both good comments I'm sure.  I'm not a Windows buf and so this code was untested.  Just hoping to show the general direction of how to integrate native OS timing into the `<chrono>` library.