# C++ chrono::duration_cast always outputs "0 seconds"

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, c++-chrono

This is my very first question here and I'm also a complete newbie at C++, but I'll do my best to be as specific as possible. Please tell me if I'm being to vague:

I am trying to measure the time it takes for a sorting method (merge sort) to sort a given array of integers by using chrono and duration_cast. Here is the code snippet in question:

```
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    mergesort(sortingArray, temp, 0, num - 1);
    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> fp_ms = t2 - t1;
    std::cout << fp_ms.count() << " seconds\n";
```

And the output I get is always "0 seconds", no matter how big I make the array it needs to sort. Even when it sorts a million integers and there is a noticeable execution time, it still gives me the same output.

I'm basically following the example given here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast

Only instead of f() I'm using my mergesort function. How can I make it measure my sorting method properly?

EDIT: I'm using minGW to compile via Powershell in Windows 10. The command looks like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 .\Merge.cpp
```

Comment: Is `mergesort` your own function?  Are you sure it is actually sorting the array?

Comment: Yes, `mergesort` is my own function. I have printed the sorted array to make sure it works.

Comment: Can you try switching printing nanoseconds instead just to make sure that it's not getting rounded to 0. Also detailing what compiler / platform might help you track down any bugs.

Comment: Okay, I switched to nanoseconds now and it gives me the same output so no progress there. I'm using minGW to compile via Powershell in Windows 10. The command looks like this: `g++ -std=c++11 .\Merge.cpp`.

Comment: Try switching to `steady_clock`.

Comment: Unfortunately, no difference there, Howard :(

Comment: What version MinGW? Perhaps this feature is not implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It looks like the `std::chrono` implementation (libstdc++) is quite poor on Windows and you won't get anything better than seconds.

**Long version:**

libstdc++ `typedef`s `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` to `std::chrono::system_clock`. According to the [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11/chrono.cc) a call to `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` will result in a call to one of the following, depending on the platform:

- `syscall(SYS_clock_gettime, CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)`, which is a Linux system call
- `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, ...)`, which is a POSIX syscall not supported by Windows
- `gettimeofday(...)`, which is a POSIX function not supported by Windows
- `std::time()` as a fallback

Thus, `std::time()` is called internally on Windows. The encoding of `std::time()` is not specified; however, most systems follow the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html):

> The time() function shall return the value of time in **seconds** since the Epoch.

Microsoft itself does [the same](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f4c8f33.aspx):

> Return the time as **seconds** elapsed since midnight, January 1, 1970, or -1 in the case of an error.

I think it is safe to say that you won't get a higher resolution with MingW's `std::chrono`.

As for your problem, you have two options:

1. If your program is running on Windows only you can build your own time measurement using [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. If you want to keep it portable use [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/chrono.html). It uses the [native Windows APIs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/chrono/appendices.html#chrono.appendices.implementation) and should offer a better resolution.

Comment: I went for the first alternative and it solved my problem. This is the implementation I used:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter

Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSkogeby:  Here is how you can build your own chrono-compatible clock base on QueryPerformanceCounter http://stackoverflow.com/a/15755865/576911  This gives you all the cool type-safety of chrono time_points and durations.