# Can Clock with direct QueryPerformanceCounter value be conforming to C++ Standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, query-performance, performancecounter, c++-chrono

Assuming I want to create `Clock` with direct `QueryPerformanceCounter` Windows API result. `QueryPerformanceCounter` Windows API returns some counter that should be divided by `QueryPerformanceFrequency` result, thus producing time in seconds.

Usually `Clock` based on `QueryPerformanceCounter` would immediately convert result to some units by multiplying by some period and dividing by `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. This is how `steady_clock` could be implemented on Windows.

But suppose that for performance reasons I want to avoid division until really needed. So `time_point` is direct `QueryPerformanceCounter` value, and `duration` is the difference of such. And I can perform arithmetic and comparison on those values most of the time, converting to some normal `duration` or `time_point` only the final result.

I'm sure it is possible. My question is: will such `Clock` be fully compatible with standard `Clock`.

Comment: do you mean this [named requirement Clock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Clock) ?

Comment: Yes, Clock named requirement

Comment: From my understanding the only requirement for a `Clock` is what @idclev463035818 already explained...
So the Concept of `Clock` is to satisfy that requirement.
the timepoint could be anything you want, it has only to represent how many ticks passed from epoch

Comment: i didnt really explain it, but the link above does list all what is needed to meet the requirement, not an expert on that, but afaik it is just about providing certain methods and other than `is_steady` the requirements on semantics are rather loose

Comment: ...so, to answer your question you would have to show your code.

Comment: i think even a simple counter that randomly increases could satisfy the requirement, though that would be a rather lousy clock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be fully compatible with the standard [Clock Requirements](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.req).  But it will compile and do what you want, most of the time.  The part that doesn't conform is that you will have to specify *something* for the `period` that your `time_point` is based on.  And that something won't necessarily correspond to physical time units.

This won't matter until you subtract two of these time_points, get a `duration`, and then compare that `duration` with something that *does* represent physical time.  Then you'll get run-time garbage.

Also if you use such a `time_point` in `sleep_until`, or `wait_until`, then your program won't sleep or wait for the intended time.

Here is an example chrono clock based on `QueryPerformanceCounter` that does nail down the physical units with `QueryPerformanceFrequency`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755865/576911

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about making `period` completely legitimate nanosecond period, but hide system-specific unit in `rep` type as it may be `a class emulating an arithmetic type`. Is it still impossible?

Comment: So the conversion to physical time happens when your custom `rep` converts to a scalar?  Might work.  Not sure.

Comment: I've researched the question myself, no, custom `rep` does not work. But my original problem has solutions. I've added my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clock with redefined `time_point` and `duration` that do not correspond to the `period` known at compile time do no meet `Clock` requirements, as Howard Hinnant explained.

---

Using *a class emulating an arithmetic type* to hide additional implementation details does not work.

As Standard does not define what is this *emulation*, the opportunity of using emulating type is only available to the clocks provided by standard implementation. As a practical proof, `std::chrono` and `boost::chrono` do not work well with `boost::rational`.

---

However, the general task to *avoid divison on each time query* has at least two practical solutions.

First solution is to follow the intention to delay division until needed, but not redefining `time_point` and `duration`. Define standard-conforming clock, and, as an extension, define the interface for raw timestamp. So, clock may have `raw_now()` method, returning `raw_time_point` type, difference of such is `raw_duration` type. `raw_time_point` may be implicitly convertible to `time_point` and `raw_duration` to `duration`.

---

Second solution is to calculate standard-conforming `time_point` for each time query, but use [libdivide](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/libdivide) library that performs fast division without division operation.

The library takes divisor and processes it so that each division using processed divisor is done using fast operations. Sure, it takes time to process divisor, but for repeated division with the same divisor it is one-time overhead. So this library looks like an ideal match for this task. (Note that the library is not useful for constants known at compile time, since in this case compiler avoids division by itself, but `QueryPerformanceFrequency` result is run-time constant).