# std::chrono nanosecond timer works on MSVC but not GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I have a simple program that uses `chrono` for timing that I had ported from MSVC to Code::Blocks. The display of the program shows the delta time from when it was started to 16 decimal places. After getting it to compile, I noticed that the timer was only moving up from the first 6 decimal places. The code remains unchanged, still using `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();` for the time, and then to calculate the delta time I use

```
double localDeltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(m_EndTime - m_StartTime).count();
localDeltaTime = localDeltaTime / 1000000000.0;
```

This clearly displays nanosecond timings, yet GCC only seems to do microseconds? Is this a known issue?

### Edit:

Here is an MRE,

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point finish = start;

    while (true)
    {
        finish = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        long double deltaTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(finish - start).count();
        deltaTime /= 1000000000.0;

        std::cout << std::setprecision(25) << deltaTime << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which versions of the compiler are you using and with which command line?

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi um, something I just realised too, I updated windows, and that may have updated my visual studio compiler too. Now they both only work with microseconds, GCC and MSVC, I was previously on 1607, now on 20h2. How can I check what compiler on visual studio and gcc? Its through codeblocks too so its not command line compiled.

Comment: Oh yeah, MinGW32, I keep getting confused with all that. I'm a little new to this

Comment: Note that there's no guarantee a timer will have nanosecond resolution.  On the boxes I've worked on `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` typically has a base resolution of 200 nanoseconds or so.

Comment: I changed nothing, but I think it might be the windows update that screwed it. Before nanoseconds was working, now it isn't. - atleast for visual studio.

Comment: @rustyx `gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.`

Comment: Off-topic: `std::setprecision(25)` is pointless, in best scenario double can store 16 significant decimal digits.

Comment: Now what do you expect: https://godbolt.org/z/cqe1Wjrrb ? Or what MinGW prints on Windows.

Comment: @MarekR Yes, but with `std::setprecision(16)` it only shows up to 6 decimals so it doesn't seem like it only times to microseconds, atleast with this, the inprecision makes it display the whole stream of data.

Comment: @asjhdbashjdbasjhdbhjb in my modification `std::fixed << std::setprecision(9)` shows seconds exactly to nanosecond precision.

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` is a typedef for one of the other clocks and it is implementation-specific on which one you get. Stick to using `std::chrono::steady_clock` specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a known MinGW issue [#5086](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5086).

It mentions these possible workarounds:

- use `std::chrono::steady_clock`
- use [Boost.chrono](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/chrono.html)
- build [your own clock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755865/485343) using `QueryPerformanceCounter` Win32 API

Regarding MSVC:

First of all, on Windows, the best possible user-space timer resolution is 100 ns.

In MSVC `system_clock` and `steady_clock` both support this resolution, so you should see 7 decimal digits changing.

**But** writing to `std::cout` takes a **long time**, on the order of 1 ms. So that's the reason why you're seeing large time steps in your version, you're essentially measuring `std::cout` time.

I rewrote the test to print the *minimum* change in the time point:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std::literals;

template<class Clock>
void runTest() {
    std::cout << typeid(Clock).name() << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto start = Clock::now();
        for (;;) {
            auto finish = Clock::now();
            if (finish != start) {
                std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << (finish - start) / 1.0s << '\n';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    runTest<std::chrono::system_clock>();
    runTest<std::chrono::steady_clock>();
    runTest<std::chrono::high_resolution_clock>();
}
```

And here's the output I got:

MSVC 19.28 (VS 2019):

```
struct std::chrono::system_clock
0.000000200
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
struct std::chrono::steady_clock
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000200
0.000000100
struct std::chrono::steady_clock
0.000000200
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
```

MinGW-w64 GCC 10.2.0 (Rev1, Built by MSYS2 project):

```
NSt6chrono3_V212system_clockE
0.000999200
0.000998600
0.000999900
0.001000800
0.000999400
NSt6chrono3_V212steady_clockE
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
0.000000100
NSt6chrono3_V212system_clockE
0.000999900
0.001001900
0.001006200
0.001016600
0.000980700
```

So in case of MinGW we can see that at least `steady_clock` provides 100 ns resolution, but unfortunately `high_resolution_clock` is an alias of `system_clock`.